# intersection of two array of objects using angularjs or javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have list01 like :

```
var list01 = [
   {
      date: **01/01/2015**,
      statut: [1,2,6],
      name: '**Name X**'
   },
   {
      date: **01/01/2015**,
      statut: [5,6],
      name: '**Name X**'
   },
   {
      date: 01/01/2016,
      statut: [5,6],
      name: 'Name Y'
   },
   ...
]
```

I want to generate list02 who contains all items that have the same name and date from list01

```
var list02 = [
   {
      date: 01/01/2015,
      name: 'Name x',
      **nbrItem: 2**
   },
   {
      date: 01/01/2016,
      statut: [5,6],
      name: 'Name Y',
      **nbrItem: 1**
   },
   ...
]
```

I want a better way to solve this problem

Comment: "a better way to solve this problem"... better than what? What are doing currently?

Comment: If you're looking to **clone** your object, [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object#answer-122190) might help you.

Comment: Also, define "better" - faster performing?  Easier to read?

Comment: [`list02 = list01.map(yourfunctioncode)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see if [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/j268ywcp/) does what you want. The basic idea is to create an empty list at the start, then loop through the original list. For each item in the original list, see if a matching item is already in your new list. If so, increment the `nbrItem` property. Otherwise, create a new object. The guts of the linked fiddle are shown below:

```
var len = list01.length;
var list02 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var foundMatch = false;
    var len2 = list02.length;
    for (var j = 0; j < len2; j++) {
        if (list02[j].date == list01[i].date && list02[j].name == list01[i].name) {
            foundMatch = true;
            list02[j].nbrItem++;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!foundMatch) {
        list02.push( {
            date: list01[i].date,
            name: list01[i].name,
            nbrItem: 1
        });
    }
}
```

`Array.prototype.map` turned out not to be a good fit in this case because you want an output with different lengths than the input. The method shown here just uses plain old for loops, which work in all browsers, even the really old ones that don't have `map`.

Comment: Thanks. That was not obvious to me.

Comment: i have edited my question. list02 must regroup items that had the same date and name

Comment: I completely rewrote my answer. Please let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: a big thanks my friend

Answer (score 2):

Edited:

```html
var list02 = [];
list01.forEach(function(item) {
  var matched = list02.filter(function(filterItem) {
    return filterItem.name==item.name && filterItem.date==item.date
  })
  if(matched.length)
    matched[0].nbrItem++
  else
    list02.push({
      date: item.date, 
      name: item.name, 
      nbrItem: 1
    });
});
```

Comment: but you must add only items that had the same name and date into the list02

Comment: Yeah, and this is exactly what it is doing, same as Austin's answer, but his answer will be more efficient for big arrays. [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MU3aoap7xONzNlzbDuiH?p=preview)